# C++ simple program help String Data

Tags: c++, string, data-structures

Thanks for helping me in advance! I am used to Java and C# but C++ is completely different. I am trying to do part B of this lab: http://cs.binghamton.edu/~sgreene/cs240-2010f/labs/lab2.html

Is this the idea that is assigned in Part B? Also I dont know what exactly is missing in the header file that deals with indef endif, etc. I did research and I dont seem to miss anything. And lastly, what does the lab assignment mean when it says: "In the [] operator, the index should be checked to confirm it is between 0 and 9. If it is not, the string "Undefined" should be returned instead." Thanks

ok so here are my updated files

```
#include "TenStrings.h"

using namespace std;

//Default Constructor
TenStrings::TenStrings()
{
    public:

    TenStrings str[10];
    str[0] = "String 1";
    str[1] = "String 2";
    str[2] = "String 3";
    str[3] = "String 4";
    str[4] = "String 5";
    str[5] = "String 6";
    str[6] = "String 7";
    str[7] = "String 8";
    str[8] = "String 9";
    str[9] = "String 10";
}
;
```

main.cpp 
--------------------------*/

```
#include "TenStrings.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    TenStrings varTen;

    std::cout << str[2] << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

also is the line missing in my header file: #include ?

Comment: Have you studied "operator overloading" yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that the assignment carries this warning:

### This is an individual assignment - you may NOT work in groups. Do not write or dictate code for anyone else, and do not use code from anyone else. If you break this rule, you may fail the entire class.

Hence I will provide only some guidance, not code.

> First I dont know where to create the
>   new data strings, whether it should be
>   in my header class or tenstrings.cpp?

The assignment says:

> Implement this TenStrings class such
>   that it acts as an array of 10
>   constant-data strings. Start with the
>   basic [] operator, and the
>   constructor.

The word "implement" is key. Until you know about [inline function definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) (which I'm guessing you haven't gotten to yet), implementation always needs to be in one of the `cpp` files (in this case, `tenstrings.cpp`.)

> Should I create an array of empty
>   strings? or an array of String1,
>   string2, string3, etc?

The assignment says:

> In the constructor, the 10 strings
>   should initially be set to "First
>   String", "Second String", etc....

In other words, the constructor for the TenString class should make the first string (i.e., at index `[0]`) have the **exact** value `"First String"`; and so on up through the tenth string (at index `[9]`) having the **exact** value `"Tenth String"`. Apparently, the intent is to be able to change these assignments through the `[]` operator, which you are to write as part of the TenString class.

I hope this helps. (I *think* that I've interpreted the assignment correctly, but I can't guarantee that.)

Oh, and by the way, there's no need for this line:

```
#include <string>
```

since the assignment specifically says *not* to use the String class.

**EDIT**: Also, the header file seems to be missing a line at the beginning. The missing line is related to the `#ifndef` / `#define` / `#endif` protection that's mentioned in the assignment.

Comment: thank you. I was not really looking for code. I really just had trouble understanding the problem and getting started. This deffinetely has helped. I will work on it and see how how far i get, thanks

Comment: i've edited my original post above. can you please take a look at it? THanks

Comment: also when I try to run this program using make i get error: <directory...> error while loading shared libraries:mysy-1.0.dll: cannot open shared object file: no such file..

Comment: @user593301: This really needs to be a separate question. But here are some tips: 1) You have the array declared as a local variable. That means it won't exist after the constructor is finished. You need to declare that array as a member of the class (meaning, among other things, that it's declared in the `.h` file.)  2) Remember that you need to define the [] operator in the TenStrings class, so that a variable whose type is `TenStrings` can act as if it's an array. If you're not sure how to do this, google "c++ operator overloading".

Comment: @user593301 (continued) 3) I have no clue what `mysy-1.0.dll` is. This error is probably in your makefile; again, that should be a separate question. (Include the contents of the makefile there.)

Comment: "using namespace std" is OK in a .cpp file. It's usually bad form in a header file, as it means anyone who uses that header file gets that line as a side-effect. I don't think you need it in the header file. (For that matter, nor do you need it in the cpp files, if you're always using the `std::` prefix where it might be needed.)